# Need explanations about notions of sub-hubble and super-hubble scales

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, universe, cosmological-inflation, observable-universe

I have often seen in the literature the notions of sub-hubble, super-hubble scales as illustrated in this diagram:

[image: diagram]

1. I don't understand this diagram: on the abscissa is the scale factor well represented? and what about the ordinate ?. I understand the 3 phases (inflation, radiation which dominates, late universe) but what are these notions of sub-hubble and super-hubble?
2. Just another question which joins the first question: by considering the episode of inflation and a primitive universe in the form of a plasma of photons, electrons, protons, don't we already consider a priori a finite and non-infinite universe?

It's always the same problem in cosmology: if I affirm that there is a content, then I can't help thinking of a container which itself can be a content etc... (Russian dolls) . When I was a kid, I often saw the reflection: cosmologists refuse to be interested in any
container.